# Parse google search result in PHP - Keyword checker

Tags: php, parsing, search

I want to do a little script, where I can Google for my keywords daily.

What is the best approach for this?

If I use the API, which i don't think there is any for this task, is there a limit?

I want to check for the first 100-200 results.

Comment: google does not take gently someone scraping their results

Comment: There is a commercial use API for that http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Comment: You may just want to set up a Google Alert for your keywords. http://www.google.com/alerts

Comment: The Problem with custom search is, you can only search a list of webpages, which is not good for keyword tracking. I want to do regular keyword search and parse it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your big problem is that Google results are very customised now - depending on what you are searching for, results can be customised based on your exact location (not just country), time of day, search history, etc.

Hence, your results probably won't be completely constant and certainly won't be the same as for somebody a few miles away with a different browser history, even if they search for exactly the same thing.

There are various SEO companies offering tools to make the results more standardised, and these tools won't break the Google Terms of Service.

Try: http://www.seomoz.org/tools and http://tools.seobook.com/firefox/rank-checker/

Comment: The Problem with this approach is, they are very bloated in the price. It's not cheap to track the keywords you want. It's hard for a startup like me to pay 100 USD+ a month, without even earning the hosting costs :(

Comment: @Herr Kaleun: Well guess what, most things cost *something*. Getting yourself off Google's bad books ("that's the guy whom we banned, as he was scraping our search") might not be exactly cheap, either.

Comment: Yes, if the site would generate the right income, it would be no problem :) 
I do not want to scrape TB's out of google, i just want to track 50 60 keywords.

Comment: @Herr You can do it, and it will work, although the data you garner from it will only tell you what a scraper searching for those terms from that IP address sees. And often, because they _know_ it's a scraper, they will return really bad results. If you still want to do it, look on Google for 'scraping google serps' and you'll get lots of scripts. I'm not linking to them or showing you their scripts because I don't think you should do this, and I would be breaking the SO terms and conditions.

Comment: How do the big guys do it then? Like for example, the services that would check for keywords? For example, SEOMoz and the other players?
I simply want to track my keywords and there is no api for this, why is this such an offense/sin for google? 
I really don't get it. 
How could and should people track their Keyword rankings on their own?
I don't know if it's paranioa but i really suspect SEOmoz and that kinds a sub-project of google themself

Comment: @Herr It is possible and there are lots of people doing it. The problem is that's a full time job, and if you're not using multiple servers with various IPs with scripts intelligent enough to beat Google's analysis then your results will be worse than useless - Google will be intentionally misleading you. If it were easy to build a tool like this, or if there were a free API that could give you exactly what you're after, then SEOMoz wouldn't be able to charge $100 a month. But it isn't easy, there is no free API.

Comment: I see, thank you for your honest answer. I will try my best, i do not want to fool google, just simply want to track my keywords and i hope i can manage it.

Thank you very much my friend

Answer (score 3):

1. Do your search manually once, copy the resulting URL that points to the results page
2. Write a PHP script that:

   - fetches the content from that URL using `file-get-contents()`
   - parses the full HTML result back to a PHP array containing only search result data that is relevant to you
   - writes the array to database or file system
3. Run the PHP-script as a cron job on your server (hourly, daily, whatever you prefer)
4. Be prepared to update your script whenever Google changes the format of its results page
5. Get yourself a lawyer

Better yet, get yourself a commercial license as indicated by mario. That way you can skip all steps above (especially 4 and 5 can be missed).

Comment: Any advice on parsing the links, paying attention to anything?
Maybe any class or piece of code that does this?

Comment: Probably too late for Herr K (sorry), but take a look at QueryPath, which can get the contents of a URL and allows you to query the HTML returned (a la jQuery in the browser, but with PHP on the server), which will be a whole lot easier than parsing the raw HTML yourself. Not too difficult to get up and running; the challenge is in points 4 and 5 of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [php script](http://thetechnofreak.com/technofreak/get-scrape-google-search-results-php/) which does the task of parsing/scraping the top 1000 results gracefully without any personalized effects by google, along with a better version called true [Google Search API](http://thetechnofreak.com/store/products/true-google-search-scraper-parser/) (which generalizes the task, returning an array of nicely formatted results)
Both of these scripts work server-side and parse the results directly from results page uging cURL and regex

Answer (score 0):

A few moths ago, I worked with [GooHackle](http://goohackle.com/) guys and they have a web application that does exactly what you're looking for, plus the cost is not high, they have under $30/month plans.

Like Blowski already said, nowadays Google results are very customized, but if you search always using the same country and query parameters, you can have a pretty accurate view of your rankings for several keywords and domains.

If you want to develop the app yourself is not going to be too difficult neither, you can use PHP or any other language to periodically do the queries and save the results in a DB. There are basically only two points to resolve, do the HTTP queries(easily done with cURL) and parse the results(you can use regex or the DOM structure). Then if you want to monitor thousands of keywords and domains, things turns a little more difficult because Google starts to ban your IP addresses.

I think that the apps like this from the "big guys" have hundreds or thousands of different IP addresses, from different countries. That allows them to collect the Google results for a huge number of keywords.

Regarding the online tool that I initially mentioned, they also have an online [Google scraper](http://goohackle.com/tools/google-parser/) that anybody can use and shows how this works, just query and parse.

Answer (score 0):

[SEOPanel](http://seopanel.in) works around a similar issue: your could download open source code and extract a simple keyword parser for your search results. The "trick" used is about slowing query searches, while project is hosted by Google (Code) self.